# Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-dashboard\index.php on line 18

Tags: easyphp

I have EasyPHP-deverser-17 installed and working well for months. Today, without any reason (i mean did not change anything), i get these error messages when opening the Dashboard:

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-dashboard\index.php on line 18

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-dashboard\index.php on line 23

I can't figure out what happened and i can't find any solution on how to fix this.

Thank you so much for any help.

Sylvain

Comment: Did you add any module or component ?
Try to stop and start your server.

Comment: Thanks Peter. No i did not add anything. And i also tried to stop and restart several times. In the meantime, i installed Wamp that works fine. So i'm not sure i will continue trying to fix the issue...

Answer (score 1):

If you have not fixed this issue since you asked this question, I found the answer on [GitHub](https://github.com/easyphp/easyphp-devserver/issues/112):

> **Step 1** - Download the link file:
>   Download Link (update): https://drive.google.com/file/d/12rP6-UM2OxO9Qmyn3FHI6AsGSOk4Avni/view?usp=sharing
>
> **Step 2** - As administrator authorization is required, authorize it.
>
> **Step 3** - On the screen click "Y" to continue ("N" to exit), and wait for the process;
>
> **Step 4** - Go to the options to start the servers in the icon that is in the system tray, or go to Dashboard and refresh the page, then start the servers in the HTTP and DB buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to follow below step worked for me.

1. Open `cmd` run as administrator.
2. Navigate to the `C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17`
3. Type cmd `lodctr /r` and press enter.
4. Success to all!